# Ionic App Availability plugin (capacitor) always returns false on android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, plugins, capacitor

the issue with my code is that it doesn’t detect the application that is being installed on the android, it always returns false.
I am following the official documentation from here (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-availability)
Here is my code:

```
import { AppAvailability } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/app-availability/ngx';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
    
app:any;
    
       constructor(
            private appAvailability: AppAvailability, 
            private platform: Platform
        ) { 
          this.app = 'com.twitter.android';
          this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.appAvailability.check(this.app)
          .then(
            (yes: boolean) => console.log(this.app + ' is available'),
            (no: boolean) => console.log(this.app + ' is NOT available')
          );
        }
        }
```

And the output is always:

```
com.twitter.android is NOT available
```

Kindly suggest me what is wrong in this? Thankyou

Comment: I didn't check this plugin before but u can try maybe to write, this.appavailablity.check(this.app).then(resp => console.log(resp));  and see what does resp return... maybe their callback approach have changed as javascript version changes over time since its been long time they didn't update the plugin... so check and tell the result

Comment: Also if u don't want to go with this plugin, there could be better choice which capacitor build plugin `https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app-launcher` which u could check if app is available and maybe launch it or do other things..

Comment: you cannot do: `.then((res)=>{console.log(res)}`  because it only passes two attributes that is whether true or false

Comment: @MostafaHarb how can I use app-launcher to check whether the app is installed or not?

Comment: `const checkCanOpenUrl = async () => {
  const { value } = await AppLauncher.canOpenUrl({ url: 'com.getcapacitor.myapp' });

  console.log('Can open url: ', value);
};`   using this way... its available in the url i linked in comment above..

Comment: @MostafaHarb this also always return false I am trying the 1.0.1 version as the latest version had errors with my project. I have tried twitter, facebook and other app packages but no progress.

Comment: well will try it after some hours and give u the solution...

Comment: sorry for not reply at time, but i tried to install the plugin and it needed capacitor update to 4.0.0 and when done every thing got not working till now lol... so anyway good that it worked ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by downgrading the version of `https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app-launcher` to `1.0.9` and adding the  tag inside the android manifest with the desired app url that I want to check from the android device.